# Remove entire <li> element if content match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have scraped html in a string and only wish to display certain list elements. For example, if the list element contains the word 'Banana' then remove entire line from html.

For example in the following block, how would I use preg_replace or similar to remove the enitire

element?

```
<ul>
  <li class="x">Apple - Green</li>
  <li class="x"><span>Orange</span> - Orange</li>
  <li id="active" class="x">Banana - Yellow</li>
  <li class="z"><span>Grapefruit</span> - Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

And end up with

```
<ul>
  <li class="x">Apple - Green</li>
  <li class="x"><span>Orange</span> - Orange</li>
  <li class="z"><span>Grapefruit</span> - Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

Bearing in mind the class and span tags are dynamic and may or may not appear.

I thought of using preg_replace but my skills are limted to only replacing the word 'Banana' but leaving 'Yellow'. I want to remove that entire line.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried .

Answer (score 1):

My PHP-specific syntax is a bit rusty but this regex would work:

`s/<li.*Banana.*?<\/li>//mg`

So this should do it:

```
$pattern = /<li.*Banana.*?<\/li>//mg;
$no_potassium = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

You could also map an array of lines not containing Banana with `preg_split` and `preg_grep`:

```
$lines = preg_grep($pattern, preg_split('/\r?\n/', $html), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

That would have the added bonus of no superfluous whitespace, not that that matters a great deal to HTML.

Comment: The //mg; caused a slight problem but once solved this did the trick. Many thanks. If I want to remove lines containing an array of words would I just stick the array variable in place of the 'Banana'?

Comment: Update - this isn't working if there is a class or span tag within the list element.

Comment: @TheTub try making the regex greedy by removing the ? - `/<li.*Banana.*<\/li>//`